# Adding boxplot below density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot and I'm trying to create this graph:

[image]

But actually, I'm just stuck here:

[image]

This is my code :

```
ggplot(diamonds)  + 
  aes(x = carat, group = cut) + 
  geom_line(stat = "density", size = 1) + 
  theme_grey() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow = 5, strip.position = "right") + 
  geom_boxplot(aes())
```

Does someone know what I can do next?

Comment: I believe you need the `ggExtra` package for this type of plot,

Comment: Do you know how it works ?

Comment: Have you tried without the `aes` in `geom_boxplot`?

Comment: It's odd/interesting that '-0.5' is the label on the y-axis.That is clearly the value mapped to the y-aesthetic, but I'm not sure how that becomes the label (unless specifically called in `labs()`, which I don't think is the case here). I'm able to replicate, however the boxplot is completely condensed and is a line.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit: As of ggplot2 3.3.0, this can be done in ggplot2 without any extension package.**

Under the package's [news](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/news/news.html), under new features:

> All geoms and stats that had a direction (i.e. where the x and y axes
> had different interpretation), can now freely choose their direction,
> instead of relying on `coord_flip()`. The direction is deduced from
> the aesthetic mapping, but can also be specified directly with the new
> `orientation` argument (@thomasp85, #3506).

The following will now work directly (replacing all references to `geom_boxploth` / `stat_boxploth` in the original answer with `geom_boxplot` / `stat_boxplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = -0.5)) +

  # horizontal boxplots & density plots
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = cut)) +
  geom_density(aes(x = carat), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  
  # vertical lines at Q1 / Q2 / Q3
  stat_boxplot(geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = ..xlower..)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = ..xmiddle..)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = ..xupper..)) +
  
  facet_grid(cut ~ .) +
  scale_fill_discrete()
```

---

**Original answer**

This can be done easily with a horizontal boxplot `geom_boxploth()` / `stat_boxploth()`, found in the [ggstance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggstance/index.html) package:

```
library(ggstance)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = -0.5)) +

  # horizontal box plot
  geom_boxploth(aes(fill = cut)) +

  # normal density plot
  geom_density(aes(x = carat), inherit.aes = FALSE) +

  # vertical lines at Q1 / Q2 / Q3
  stat_boxploth(geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = ..xlower..)) +
  stat_boxploth(geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = ..xmiddle..)) +
  stat_boxploth(geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = ..xupper..)) +
  
  facet_grid(cut ~ .) +
  
  # reproduce original chart's color scale (o/w ordered factors will result
  # in viridis scale by default, using the current version of ggplot2)
  scale_fill_discrete()
```

[image: plot]

If you are limited to the ggplot2 package for one reason or another, it can still be done, but it would be less straightforward, since `geom_boxplot()` and `geom_density()` go in different directions.

**Alternative 1**: calculate the box plot's coordinates, & flip them manually before passing the results to `ggplot()`. Add a density layer in the normal way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

p.box <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = carat)) + geom_boxplot()    
p.box.data <- layer_data(p.box) %>%
  select(x, ymin, lower, middle, upper, ymax, outliers) %>%
  mutate(cut = factor(x, labels = levels(diamonds$cut), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-x)

ggplot(p.box.data) +
  
  # manually plot flipped boxplot
  geom_segment(aes(x = ymin, xend = ymax, y = -0.5, yend = -0.5)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = lower, xmax = upper, ymin = -0.75, ymax = -0.25, fill = cut),
            color = "black") +
  geom_point(data = . %>% unnest(outliers),
             aes(x = outliers, y = -0.5)) +
  
  # vertical lines at Q1 / Q2 / Q3
  geom_vline(data = . %>% select(cut, lower, middle, upper) %>% gather(key, value, -cut),
             aes(xintercept = value)) +
  
  # density plot
  geom_density(data = diamonds, aes(x = carat)) +

  facet_grid(cut ~ .) +
  labs(x = "carat") +
  scale_fill_discrete()
```

**Alternative 2**: calculate the density plot's coordinates, & flip them manually before passing the results to `ggplot()`. Add a box plot layer in the normal way. Flip the whole chart:

```
p.density <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, group = cut)) + geom_density()    
p.density.data <- layer_data(p.density) %>%
  select(x, y, group) %>%
  mutate(cut = factor(group, labels = levels(diamonds$cut), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-group)
p.density.data <- p.density.data %>%
  rbind(p.density.data %>% 
          group_by(cut) %>% 
          filter(x == min(x)) %>% 
          mutate(y = 0) %>% 
          ungroup())

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = -0.5, y = carat)) +

  # manually flipped density plot
  geom_polygon(data = p.density.data, aes(x = y, y = x), 
               fill = NA, color = "black") +

  # box plot
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = cut, group = cut)) +

  # vertical lines at Q1 / Q2 / Q3
  stat_boxplot(geom = "hline", aes(yintercept = ..lower..)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "hline", aes(yintercept = ..middle..)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "hline", aes(yintercept = ..upper..)) +

  facet_grid(cut ~ .) +
  scale_fill_discrete() +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Although need little upgrade :)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(wrapr)

subplots <-
diamonds$cut %>%
  unique() %>%
  tibble(Cut = .) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number() - 1) %$%
  map2(
    .x = Cut,
    .y = rn,
    ~annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(
      diamonds %>%
        filter(cut == .x) %.>%
        ggplot(data = .) + 
        aes(x = carat, fill = cut) + 
        annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(
          ggplot(data = .) +
            geom_boxplot(
              aes(x = -1, y = carat),
              fill = .y + 1
            ) +
            coord_flip() +
            theme_void() +
            theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 20))
        )) +
        geom_line(stat = 'density', size = 1) +
        theme_void() +
        theme(plot.margin = margin(t = .y * 100 + 10, b = (4 - .y) * 100 + 40)) 
    ))
  )

ggplot() + subplots
```